# Close "Loading" form on Backgroundworker run completed

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a Form which accepts certain inputs from User.
When User clicks "OK", I insert the User entered inputs into Settings and store it. This process is done in Main Form and is somewhat long(around 15 sec)

So I am doing this work in Background Worker.

Following is my Code:

```
frmProgress progressBar ;

private void SomeMethod()
{
        if (frm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {                
            List<Criteria> selectedCriterias = new List<Criteria>(frm.SelectedCriteria);
            bool isOverWriteExistingCriteria = frm.IsOverwriteExistingCriteria;
            object[] args = new object[] {selectedCriterias, isOverWriteExistingCriteria};

            // STart Background worker
            backgroundFillCriteria.RunWorkerAsync(args);

            // Display my progressForm
            progressBar = new frmProgress("Updating Specified Criteria. . .");
            if (progressBar != null && !progressBar.IsDisposed)
                progressBar.ShowDialog();
        }
}

private void backgroundFillCriteria_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        object[] args = e.Argument as object[];
        List<Criteria> scanAlertCriterias = args[0] as List<Criteria>;
        bool isOverwriteExistingCriteria = (bool)args[1];

        UpdateCriteria(scanCriterias, isOverwriteExistingCriteria);
}

private void (List<Criteria> scanCriterias, bool isOverwriteExistingCriteria)
{
// Does all processing
}

private void backgroundCriteria_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (progressBar != null)
            {
                progressBar.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

My Problem is - my Criterias are Updated - but Application hangs on Progressform. And I cannot proceed

I guess i am disposing it in a wrong way !

Please help !!

Comment: Explain _hangs_. Stop working? Error Messages? And if it stops working why don't you show the code resposible of this problem? The `UpdateCriteria` seems to be at the center of this problem.

Comment: Background worker has a specific `WorkerReportsProgress` property and matching `ProgressChanged` Event to help you with this. You can show a modal form but update it from the ProgressChanged event

Comment: Does the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` have an [error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? is progressBar null?

Comment: Progressbar is not null - That check is made in each method. The Application shows msg - "Application has stopped working!". Update Criteria() method has some validations and then it stores the user specified parameters into a variable

Comment: "Application has stopped working" is not a "hang". That's a crash (i.e. exception). Please investigate your problem enough so that you know _what_ the exception is, and please edit your question so that it is accurate. I.e. uses the correct terminology, the actual exception information -- including exception name, message, and stack trace -- and does not use the phrase "hang" to describe a "crash".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem...I was updating datagridview - UI - part of mainform from backgroundworker which was creating problem !

I am new to coding and hence made such a mistake..

Thank you for every one's help !